# Principal Symbol for the Ricci-DeTurck Flow

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

I am following some lecture notes on Ricci flow and reached the section where we linearize the Ricci tensor and obtain the principal symbol for the resulting operator.  We have $T \in \: \Gamma(Sym^2 T^{*}M)$ smooth, fixed and positive definite and then compute the time derivative for the divergence of $G(T)$:

$\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\delta G(T)  \bigg)Z  = -T \bigg((\delta G(h))^{\#},Z\bigg) + \bigg<h,\nabla T(.,.,Z) - \frac{1}{2}\nabla_{Z}T \bigg>,  $

where $\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}=h$, $Z$ an arbitrary vector field and $G(T)=T-\frac{1}{2}(tr \: T)h$.

The notes then say that this implies

$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}T^{-1}\delta G(T) = -\delta G(h)\: + \:\: ...$

where the dots indicate terms which don't have derivatives of $h$.  I see that you can apply $T^{-1}$ as it doesn't depend on $t$ and then lose the $Z$ as it is arbitrary, but not sure exactly what happens to the right-hand side such that we end up with $-\delta G(h)$ or where the sharp goes.

Comment: I gotta admit that, despite my preference for nice abstract notation, I only like what I invent myself. So when faced with deciphering someone else's abstract notation like this, I start by converting it all to local coordinates and write the tensors with indices. Here, it's particularly confusing, at least for me, with the dependence on $t$.

Comment: Yes, this is why I am confused, I have studied other treatments of the Ricci-DeTurck flow in Chow and others and it is completely explicit and done in indices, so I find this treatment difficult to decipher.

Comment: I don't see why the sharp has been dropped, should I just convert to indices, do the calculation and then convert back to the notation of the lecture notes at the end?  Not sure what else to do.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the definition of $G(T)$. It should be $G(T) = T -\frac 12 tr(T)\cdot \mathbf g$.

Comment: I think in Peter Topping, Lecture notes on Ricci flow, he refers to do computations in a coordinate-free way. Some people refer to this way. This avoids local coordinate sickness. Of course, one of the drawbacks is "a heavier notation"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is from the *Lecture notes on Ricci flow* from Peter Topping. He mentions that he uses the symbol $T$ as the symmetric, positive definite bilinear form and also for the map $\Gamma(TM^\ast) \to \Gamma(TM^\ast)$ induced by $T$ and the metric $g$ in the following way
$$
T(\alpha)(Z)=T(\alpha^\#,Z)
$$
where $\alpha^\#$ is the dual vector field to the $1$-form $\alpha$ with respect to $g$. Thus looking at 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\delta G(T)  \bigg)Z  &=& -T \bigg((\delta G(h))^{\#},Z\bigg) + \bigg<h,\nabla T(.,.,Z) - \frac{1}{2}\nabla_{Z}T \bigg> \\
&=& -T(\delta G(h))(Z) + \ldots
\end{eqnarray*}
 we just apply to the equation the inverse of $T$ to obtain your desired expression (note that $\delta G(T)$ is a $1$-form)

Comment: Hi this is correct, I was working from Topping's lecture notes on Ricci flow.  Also, once we have the desired expression he says that this implies that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} L_{(T^{-1} \delta G(T))^{\#}}g = -L_{(\delta G(T))^{\#}} + ... $

 where $L$ is the Lie derivative.  So, it has to be a sharp as it needs to be a vector field in the direction of which the Lie derivative acts, but why is it $\delta G(T)$ and not $\delta G(h)$?

Comment: Also, in this expression with the Lie derivatives the term on the right-hand side involves a second derivative of $h$ and the dots indicate terms which contain $h$ and its first derivative.

Comment: I've thought about it and I think that the fact that Topping has it with a $T$ rather than a $h$ must be a typo, as it changes back to $h$ when he linearizes the operator, then the implication comes from definition of the Lie derivative.

Comment: That would have been my guess too.